# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused. 2FA

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, gmail

I had a problems with emails on my production laravel application, so I add schedule command for queue work in Kernel file. Emails start working for a day, but then I get connection refused error when trying to send emails or login with gmail account.

I did not change any database configs in .env or any other configurations. The only thing I did is enabled 2fa on my gmail account which I am using for sending and receiving emails and user login with gmail.

Comment: Probably your IP is blacklisted by firewall because of sending many requests.

Comment: Thanks, I am blacklisted